# Rails view rendering is slow in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm dockerizing a Rails application, and I'm not sure why the views render so slow. It takes nearly 2 seconds to navigate between any two pages, with some pages taking longer. This problem does not exist when I run the application outside of Docker.

I am using Docker Desktop on a 2015 MBP with 16GB of memory.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

# replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall \
    libpq-dev libvips-dev libvips-tools

# python dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs921/ghostscript-9.21.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf ghostscript-9.21.tar.gz && cd ghostscript-9.21 && \
    ./configure && make && make install

RUN wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.8.0/node-v10.8.0.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf node-v10.8.0.tar.gz && cd node-v10.8.0 && \
    ./configure && make -j4 && make install

WORKDIR /app

RUN gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
RUN gem install foreman -v 0.85.0

RUN npm install -g yarn
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "rm -f /app/tmp/pids/server.pid && foreman start -f Procfile.dev"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - npm_packages:/app/node_modules
      - bundler_gems:/usr/local/bundle/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 8888:8888
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - mailcatcher
    environment:
      PGHOST: postgres
      PGUSER: postgres
      PGPASSWORD: "password"
      RAILS_ENV: development
      RACK_ENV: development
      NODE_ENV: development

  mailcatcher:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "gem install mailcatcher && mailcatcher --ip 0.0.0.0 --foreground"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - npm_packages:/app/node_modules
      - bundler_gems:/usr/local/bundle/
    ports:
      - 1080:1080
      - 1025:1025

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - 54320:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"

volumes:
  postgres:
  redis:
  npm_packages:
  bundler_gems:
```

Everything works, it is just very slow.

```
duration=1623.74 view=1622.89
```

Comment: Bind mounts in Docker for Mac are [known to be very slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#performance-issues-solutions-and-roadmap).  If you delete all of your `volumes:`, does the application run better?  (The two besides `/app` also have the side effect of preventing Docker from ever seeing an update to your installed packages; you wouldn't want any of these in a production environment.)

Comment: I'll try this today. I don't run docker in production, so that is no problem. I appreciate the info though, for sure. To be honest, I had some other stuff in my Dockerfile and I didn't have the gems/modules in mounts, but then I found a blog post that literally said "all of the other examples are bad, this is a real world example from an actual user" and showed to do it with mounts. I'm just learning about it...so the way it was worded seemed authoritative.

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of your recommended way of handling the Gemfile and package.json files? I'd love to go the "golden path" if there is one.

Comment: I found https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/ruby-on-whales-docker-for-ruby-rails-development which is working great. It seems the `:cached` option was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a known problem with docker-compose running on Mac OS.

Try adding the line `127.0.0.1 localunixsocket.local` to the file `/etc/hosts`

Found on: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3419#issuecomment-221793401

Comment: It didn't make a difference, unfortunately. Thanks though!